Create setup project with all dependencies in VS2022
I have a.net WPF project. I would like to build a set up project so that I create an MSI for installing the build on other machines.
I have tried creating a Setup project and added Project Output, Content files, but the Detected Dependencies is empty
Any idea how can I ensure all the dependencies is included in the MSI.
I need to include a number of frameworks and packages with the install file.
I am using Visal Studio 2022
I have also tried the steps in Deploy a .NET Windows Desktop app with ClickOnce - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn
However this does not provide me a completely offline deployment process
Any idea what I am missing ?
(see screenshot)


I would research MSI and Merge Modules (MSM). Normally in the MSI world dependencies are installed with either merge modules or installed as part of a boot strapper (setup.exe)

I would have thought this is straightforward and tested process to create a deployed app in Visual Studio 2022. I have looked at Merge modules, but not have much luck there. I am exploring the Publish Option in VS2022. Will update this post

Hi, I am following the steps outlined in
Deploy a .NET Windows Desktop app with ClickOnce - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn However this does not seem to give a completely offline deployment process as I rely on accessing a fileshare. Can anyone shed any light on this please
